# Dynamic value for an element using property expansion

Tags: groovy, soapui

Referring property expansion from [here](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html)

One of the element of the soap request is defined as follows.
`<ns:PRODUCTID>${=def list = [12, 13,12];list.join(',')}</ns:PRODUCTID>`

And when the request is submitted, it evaluates correctly and sends out the request as below(from the raw request):
`<ns:PRODUCTID>12,13,12</ns:PRODUCTID>`

However, could not get it working a dynamic value as shown below, i mean it is leading below error
`<ns:PRODUCTID>${=def a = (int)(Math.random()*5);def list = [];a.times {list.add((int)(Math.random()*1000))};list.join(',')}</ns:PRODUCTID>`

But the same script runs perfectly fine when it is run separately.
[image]
Error below:

> startup failed:
>   Script16.groovy: 1: expecting '}', found '' @ line 1, column 94.
>      add((int)(Math.random()*1000))
>                                    ^
>   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: expecting '}', found '' @ line 1, column 94.
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:139)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:107)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:163)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:839)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:544)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:520)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:497)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:306)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:287)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:770)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:761)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.resolvers.EvalPropertyResolver.doEval(EvalPropertyResolver.java:191)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.resolvers.EvalPropertyResolver.resolveProperty(EvalPropertyResolver.java:170)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpander.expand(PropertyExpander.java:180)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpander.expandProperties(PropertyExpander.java:113)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.PropertyExpansionRequestFilter.filterWsdlRequest(PropertyExpansionRequestFilter.java:45)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filterAbstractHttpRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:37)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:31)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:184)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   Caused by: Script16.groovy:1:94: expecting '}', found ''
>       at groovyjarjarantlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.closableBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:8620)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.appendedBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:11397)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.pathElement(GroovyRecognizer.java:11349)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.pathExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:11464)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.postfixExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:13175)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.unaryExpressionNotPlusMinus(GroovyRecognizer.java:13144)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.powerExpressionNotPlusMinus(GroovyRecognizer.java:12848)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.multiplicativeExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12780)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.additiveExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12450)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.shiftExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:9664)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.relationalExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12355)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.equalityExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12279)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.regexExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12227)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.andExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12195)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.exclusiveOrExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12163)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.inclusiveOrExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12131)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.logicalAndExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12099)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.logicalOrExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12067)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.conditionalExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:4842)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.assignmentExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:7988)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.expression(GroovyRecognizer.java:9841)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.expressionStatementNoCheck(GroovyRecognizer.java:8314)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.expressionStatement(GroovyRecognizer.java:8739)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1274)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:757)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:130)
>       ... 30 more
>   1 error
>   ;list.join(',')}

Answer (score 2):

Seems that in property expansion the curly braces `{}` are not allowed inside `${= ... }` because `${=` close with any `}` character from any closure, loop, method.. you try to add it.

Also trying to escape the close `\}` inside `${= ... }` does not help.

You can not even use `}` in a `String`, the follow code throws the same exception in *SOAPUI*:

```
<ns:PRODUCTID>${=return '}'}</ns:PRODUCTID>
```

The only way that you can use `}` here seems that is nesting expression like `${= ... ${= ... } }`. For example the follow nested exceptions works:

```
<ns:PRODUCTID>${= 5 + ${= 3+4 } }</ns:PRODUCTID> 
// in raw View you will see <ns:PRODUCTID>12</ns:PRODUCTID>
```

However they also can not help because individually each one has the same problem with `}` from closures, loops, methods.

Seems that the parser for property expansion which implements *SOAPUI* can not deal with this. Good catch, maybe you can request a new feature.

I don't add a workaround using groovy script to save the result in a property, and then use it in your request since I'm totally sure that you know how to do it `:)`

Comment: Thank you for the insight, and your time. And I learnt from your reply that nested example for property expansion, @albciff. Yes, I can use script approach. Just I was trying that property expansion and no idea that  it won't work or probably not much exploited in-line script by the users. May be I can check with SmartBear, but from the above stacktrace, it looks like problem is not from SoapUI side.

Comment: @Rao I think it's from *SOAPUI*; right the exception is thrown by `AntlrParserPlugin` class however IMO is due to the input script passed by `SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine` which I think is wrong ( because is parsing incorrectly as I said the `}` ... ). `:-)`.

Comment: Sorry for being late, Thank you again. By the way, the same is [posted](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Is-it-possible-to-have-a-closure-in-the-inline-property/td-p/118430) in SmartBear forum

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the syntax error is either. But try this:

```
(0..(Math.random() * 5 as Integer)).collect { Math.random() * 1000 as Integer }.join(',')
```

Comment: Thank you @Emmanuel Rosa. Unfortunately, that did not help. Still same result. Is it getting confused with inner closure as it has `{..}`?

Comment: Aaahh, yes, I bet it's being thrown off by the curly-braces. "...the remaining content up to the closing brace will be evaluated as a script." It means you can't use any block structures (ex. closures, loops, ifs, etc). Maybe you can escape them: \}

Comment: Looks `{ or }` are not required to escape in xml as that also did not help. However, property expansion is using soapui's own syntax and may likely causing problem while [parsing](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui/soapui/4.0.1.0/com/eviware/soapui/support/scripting/groovy/SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java) @ 148 line.